# Варианты хранения товаров в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Учусь работать с БД, подскажите как правильней хранить товары, есть несколько разных видов, грамотней делать разные таблицы, типа:

`pizza` `drink` `cake`

или же делать одну таблицу `products` и различать их по полю:

`type`, `type-pizza` `type-drink`. Или может есть способ лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Таблица **ProductType**, в которой инфа о типах продуктов и т.п.
2. Таблица **Products**, в котором будет внешний ключ на таблицу **ProductType**.

Если каких-то методанных по типу продуктов нету, то можно одну таблицу **Products**, в которой будет строковый столбец `ProductType`.